# How will change api request to get the result on the basis of condition?

Tags: prometheus

I load in Prometheus some custom metrics

I wrote this API request

```
http://prometheus01/api/v1/query_range?query=count(kpi_metrics)&start=1515747230&end=1515750830&step=60
```

returned

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[{"metric":{},"values":[[1515747230,"39"],[1515747290,"39"],[1515747350,"39"],[1515747410,"39"],[1515747470,"39"],[1515747530,"39"],[1515747590,"39"],[1515747650,"39"],[1515747710,"39"],[1515747770,"39"],[1515747830,"39"],[1515747890,"39"],[1515747950,"39"],[1515748010,"39"],[1515748070,"39"],[1515748130,"39"],[1515748190,"39"],[1515748250,"39"],[1515748310,"39"],[1515748370,"39"],[1515748430,"39"],[1515748490,"39"],[1515748550,"39"],[1515748610,"39"],[1515748670,"39"],[1515748730,"39"],[1515748790,"39"],[1515748850,"39"],[1515748910,"39"],[1515748970,"39"],[1515749030,"39"],[1515749090,"39"],[1515749150,"39"],[1515749210,"39"],[1515749270,"39"],[1515749330,"39"],[1515749390,"39"],[1515749450,"39"],[1515749510,"39"],[1515749570,"39"],[1515749630,"39"],[1515749690,"39"],[1515749750,"39"],[1515749810,"39"],[1515749870,"39"],[1515749930,"39"],[1515749990,"39"],[1515750050,"39"],[1515750110,"39"],[1515750170,"39"],[1515750230,"39"],[1515750290,"39"],[1515750350,"39"],[1515750410,"39"],[1515750470,"39"],[1515750530,"39"],[1515750590,"39"],[1515750650,"39"],[1515750710,"39"],[1515750770,"39"],[1515750830,"39"]]}]}}
```

this good.

After I want to get information if value satisfies the condition

```
kpi_metrics<1
```

I wrote API request

```
http://prometheus01/api/v1/query_range?query=count(kpi_metrics<1)&start=1515747230&end=1515750830&step=60
```

BUT prometheus returned only

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[]}}
```

How will change api request to get the result on the basis of condition kpi_metrics<1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query and result is correct, all of the time series of kpi_metrics are 39 which is not less than 1.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow return for example zero if the result is null?

Comment: You want `kpi_metrics< bool 1`.

Comment: I want get only kpi_metrics which satisfy the condition kpi_metrics<1